# all the same position of each sublist and create a new list

Tags: python, list, sublist

I wanted to create a new list with the same positions of each sublist 
is it possible to create?

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[a,b,c],[d,e,f]
```

**I wanted to create a new list**

```
new_list = [[1,4,a,d],[2,5,b,e],[3,6,c,f]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip()`:

```
list(zip(*list1))
```